# Delayed rendering of the image - Skia ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, skiasharp

I'm trying to draw a set of images with SkiaSharp, convert them to byte array, and send to `HttpContext` stream. For some reason, every **image is being displayed in the browser only when the next image has been rendered** and sent to the HTTP stream.

- After rendering the 1st image, browser shows empty white area, no image
- After rendering the 2nd image, browser shows 1st image
- After rendering the 3rd image, browser shows 2nd image, and so on

Here is the Web API controller. Uncommenting second `drawShapes` call will make it work, but I would like to understand why image rendering is delayed. Maybe I just don't call some important method, like `Flush` or something similar?

Also, this is not an ASP issue, because I tried rendering images with [System.Drawing.Common](https://kontext.tech/article/641/draw-images-in-aspnet-core-5) and images were rendered in real time without delay.

**Does anybody know what is missing in this method?**

```
[Route("/source")]
public async Task Get()
{
  // Initialize Skia

  var res = new byte[1000];
  var boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  var generator = new Random();
  var map = new SKBitmap(250, 250);
  var canvas = new SKCanvas(map);
  var inPaint = new SKPaint
  {
    Color = SKColors.Black,
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High
  };
  var exPaint = new SKPaint
  {
    Color = SKColors.White,
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.Low
  };

  // Create HTTP stream

  Response.ContentType = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" + boundary;

  var outputStream = Response.Body;
  var cancellationToken = Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted;

  // Create method posting images to HTTP stream 

  async Task drawShapes()
  {
    using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(map))
    {
      var pos = generator.Next(50, 150);
      canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, 250, 250, exPaint);
      canvas.DrawCircle(pos, pos, 20, inPaint);
      res = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp, 100).ToArray();
    }

    var header = $"--{ boundary }\r\nContent-Type: image/webp\r\nContent-Length: { res.Length }\r\n\r\n";
    var headerData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);

    await outputStream.WriteAsync(headerData);
    await outputStream.WriteAsync(res);
    await outputStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n"));
  }

  // Start HTTP stream

  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    //while (true)
    {
      await drawShapes();
      //await drawShapes(); // After uncommenting this shows the image (the previous one)
    }
  });
}
```

[Reproducible sample](https://github.com/artemiusgreat/SkiaAspCore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in SkiaSharp discussions.
https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/discussions/1975

Possible solutions are to make sure to `Encode` image only after all drawings are done or to call `Encode` on bitmap instead of image.

The simplest one is to replace this line.

```
//res = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp, 100).ToArray();  // wrong
res = map.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Webp, 100).ToArray();      // correct
```